# Deactivating a Salesforce Flow via the Metadata API

Tags: visual-workflow, api, metadata-api

It is my understanding right now the only way to deactivate a Salesforce flow is to retrieve the FlowDefinition file and set the active version number to zero

Is using workbench or VS Code the only way to retrieve this file? I see GearSet has a way to do this, so theoretically, do they have like a script that pulls this file down and sets the version number to 0?

Is there really not a way to do this via the Metadata API?

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FlowDefinition xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <activeversionNumber>0</activeversionNumber>
</FlowDefinition>
```

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387737&type=1

[image]

Comment: Not sure why I got the downvote? If Im mistaken please correct me.

Comment: I assume you mean "deactivate through the API" here? Clicking the "deactivate" button in the flow itself worked perfectly fine in my instance the last time I tried it (maybe a week ago?), but I'm guessing that isn't what you're looking to do here.

Comment: Yes - via the API - thank you Stephen

Comment: the link you posted is using the MDAPI (i.e. Workbench uses the MDAPI to deploy the change)

Comment: Yes but my understanding is that you would need to retrieve that update the file and then deploy it like a package.xml file? 

As an app I would like the ability to deactivate and activate the flow by passing some kind of status to the target org. Is that possible?

Comment: Are you try to deactivate from Apex?

Comment: Im trying to deactivate a flow from an app I created. So my question is if I need to use workbench to do so, how do I do so using the API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating flow status can be achieved using [Tooling REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.192.0.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_rest_overview.htm) by `FlowDefinitionId`

To disable flow definition, set version number 0 
`req.setBody( '{"Metadata": {"activeVersionNumber":0}}');`

To activate flow definition, specify the version number to activate e.g 20 
`req.setBody( '{"Metadata": {"activeVersionNumber":20}}');`

Here's a sample code in apex using user session Id as authorization for simplicity, use access token (OAuth) when calling the API from the external app.

```
Static string myDomain = 'https://yourdomain.my.salesforce.com';

private static HttpRequest buildHttpReq(String endpoint, String method){
   HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
   req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
   req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
   req.setMethod(method);
   return req;
}

public static String queryFlowDef(){
   //find the flowdefinitionid

   String flowLabel='FlowMasterLabel';
   //adapt query accordingly, here retrieving latest flow version
   String queryEndpoint = myDomain+ '/services/data/v55.0/tooling/query/?q=Select+DefinitionId+from+Flow+Where+MasterLabel=\'' + flowLabel +  '\'order+by+VersionNumber+desc+limit+1';

   HttpRequest req = buildHttpReq(queryEndpoint,'GET');

   Http httpreq = new Http();
   HttpResponse res = httpreq.send(req);
   String response = res.getBody();
   Map<String,Object> rmp = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeuntyped(response);
   List<Object> lstObt = (List<Object>)rmp.get('records');
   Map<String,Object> mapRec = (Map<String,Object>)lstObt[0];

   String defId = (String)mapRec.get('DefinitionId');
   System.debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, defId );
   return defId;
}

public static void disableFlow(){
  String flowDefId = queryFlowDef();
  HttpRequest req = buildHttpReq(myDomain+'/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/FlowDefinition/'+flowDefId,'PATCH');

  //to disable flow set version number 0
  req.setBody( '{"Metadata": {"activeVersionNumber":0}}');

  //to reactivate flow version specify the version number e.g 20
  //req.setBody( '{"Metadata": {"activeVersionNumber":20}}');

  Http http = new Http();
  HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
  String response = res.getBody();
  System.debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, response );
  System.debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, res.getStatusCode() );    
}
```

Additional references:

[FlowDefinition tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_flowdefinition.htm)

[Metadatype FlowDefintion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.242.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_flowdefinition.htm)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @andrew mark the answer as accepted, if this answers your question :)

Comment: Will need to test this but this is helpful from the other stuff Ive seen so I will!